# Spell Checker with Java, have to print out specific line

Tags: java, dictionary, cmd, spell-checking

- All the above and then print out the line number of the misspelled word and the line. Ex *1: I am a fox that lives in a huse*
- All of this should be printed on the command line

Comment: First off, you have the file lines. All of them. They are in the List named **check_file**. As for the line number, if you want the literal line number then the iteration index (i) + 1 works for this. If you want the 0 based number then just use the current iteration value of `i`. Once you know the word in the line that is in error you can get the starting index of that word in the line by using the **String.indexOf()** method. Now you know where to place your `^^^`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd i hve posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have used rapid jSpell checker for spell check
note:- generate your own API key

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SOTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Load text file into List
            List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Words.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            //Iterate List to scan the spell error
            for (String line : list) {
                for(String err:spellCheck(line)){
                    if(line.contains(err)) {
                        line = line.replace(err, "^^"+err+"^^");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static List<String> spellCheck(String input) throws IOException {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();     
        byte[] postData  = new String("{\t\"language\": \"enUS\",\t\"fieldvalues\": \""+input+"\",\t\"config\": {\t\t\"forceUpperCase\": false,\t\t\"ignoreIrregularCaps\": false,\t\t\"ignoreFirstCaps\": true,\t\t\"ignoreNumbers\": true,\t\t\"ignoreUpper\": false,\t\t\"ignoreDouble\": false,\t\t\"ignoreWordsWithNumbers\": true\t}}").getBytes();

        String request = "https://jspell-checker.p.rapidapi.com/check";
        URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "x-rapidapi-host", "jspell-checker.p.rapidapi.com"); 
        conn.setRequestProperty( "x-rapidapi-key", "32efb09328msh3e3b62d34ac8cfcp1467a4jsnb3ef821b4b23"); 
        conn.setRequestProperty( "content-type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "useQueryString", "true");

        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write( postData );
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        String strCurrentLine;
        while ((strCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            final String regex = "\"word\":\"[a-zA-Z]*\"";
            final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strCurrentLine);

            while (matcher.find()) {
                results.add(matcher.group(0).split(":")[1].replace("\"", ""));
            }

        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

input inside **Words.txt**

```
this is example
thiss is example
my Dog is hudden under cor
```

**output**

```
this is example
^^thiss^^ is example
my Dog is ^^hudden^^ under ^^cor^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This types of problem's solution is best to solve with hashTable. However, you need to do it this way, here is the solution without jSpell.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class FinalProject {
    private static  List<String> word;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 0)
        {
          System.out.println("File name not specified");
          System.exit(1);
        }
       SpellCheck(args[0]);
    }
    public static List<String> ScanFile(String file){
        Path path = Paths.get(file);
        try{
         word = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       } catch(IOException e) {

       }
        return word;
    }
    public static void SpellCheck(String file)
    {
        int lineNumber;
        List<String> word_list = ScanFile("..\\test\\dict.txt");
        List<String> check_file = ScanFile(file);
        String[] lineWords;
        Boolean correctSpelled;
        String currWord, dictWord ;
        for(int i = 0; i < check_file.size(); i++)
        {
            lineWords = check_file.get(i).trim().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]","").split(" ");
            lineNumber = i+1;
            for (int j = 0; j < lineWords.length; j++)
            {
                currWord = lineWords[j].toLowerCase();
                correctSpelled = false;
                for(int k = 0; k < word_list.size() && !correctSpelled; k++)
                {
                    dictWord = word_list.get(k).trim().toLowerCase();
                    if(currWord.equals(dictWord))
                    {
                        correctSpelled = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!correctSpelled)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error found on line number " + lineNumber);
                    System.out.println(check_file.toString() + " -> " + "\"" + currWord + "\"");
                }
            }// every word for loop
        }// every line for loop
    }//end spellChecker
}// end class
```

inputFile.txt contains

```
I am a fox that lives in a huse
```

args[0] is your dictionary.txt file

output:

```
Error found on line number 1
[I am a fox that lives in a huse] -> "huse"
```

I would try for that underline ^^^ thing. However, I have to go out. The main problem is solved. Try it. If it works, hit me a thumbs up. :)